# Django implementation of default value in database

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, django-models

I had a field on a model with was:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    some_field = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
```

Then I changed my model to:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    some_field = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='')
```

When I ran `django-admin sqlmigrate somemodels somemigration` to check my migration I found the following changes:

```
ALTER TABLE "somemodels" ALTER COLUMN "some_field" SET DEFAULT '';
UPDATE "somemodels" SET "some_field" = '' WHERE "some_field" IS NULL;
ALTER TABLE "somemodels" ALTER COLUMN "some_field" SET NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE "somemodels" ALTER COLUMN "some_field" DROP DEFAULT;
```

I am not understanding why the Django apply a `DROP DEFAULT` in the table since I am *creating* a default value. If this is correct, how does Django implement the default values?

Information about my tools:

- Postgresql 9.5;
- Django 1.11b1;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The comments to [django/db/backends/base/schema.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/backends/base/schema.py), starting ln. 571, detail the steps involved here:

> When changing a column NULL constraint to NOT NULL with a given default value, we need to perform 4 steps:
>
> 1. Add a default for new incoming writes
> 2. Update existing NULL rows with new default
> 3. Replace NULL constraint with NOT NULL
> 4. Drop the default again.

Django does not usually use the built-in SQL default to set values (remember that Django can use callable values for defaults). You can find more information in this [rejected bug report](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28000).

Comment: Thank you a lot! In the bug report you posted, someone still says "Django uses database defaults to set values on existing rows in a table. It doesn't leave the default values in the database so dropping the default is correct behavior.". Seems some sort of Django's optimization.

Comment: @lucastamoios I'm not positive...that seems to be different from the first bullet point in the comment, which *seems* to be just a safeguard for incoming values during the migration...