# Default value not setting Boolean Field Pgsql

Tags: django, postgresql

In my project I have created a boolean field with default value as false using django models. But whenever I am trying to save into that table I am getting the error saying that **null value in column "dmz" violates not-null constraint**
what could be the reason. What am doing wrong

This is my model field

```
 dmz = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=False)
```

**Edited**

When I did the

`python manage.py sqlmigrate subnets 0014_subnet_dmz`

I am getting  the generated sql as this

```
ALTER TABLE "subnets_subnet" ADD COLUMN "dmz" boolean DEFAULT true NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE "subnets_subnet" ALTER COLUMN "dmz" DROP DEFAULT;
```

ie default value is dropping . How can I preserve this ?

Comment: I this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43456944/django-implementation-of-default-value-in-database).

Comment: Hmm. But this is the case at the time of creating a new column

Comment: As the answer says, Django does not add default values to the SQL schema. It doesn't matter whether you are adding or modifying a column.

Comment: Oh. Then I have to  add the default value by running the sql on the database right ? . Is there any other method ? Anyway thanks for your help :)

Comment: You could use [`RunSQL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/migration-operations/#runsql) to add the default. That way you have a record of it in your migration.